# lambdas: this capture ignores constness (vs std::bind)

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a little example here below that has two functions (getFoo1...2) that returns a std::function.

- In both cases the getters are const.
- getFoo1 generates the return type by using a lambda with a this capture.
- getFoo2 generates the return type by using std::bind.
- In both cases the real function is non-const.
- The lambda case compiles fine (therefore constness lost...).
- The binder complains about constness of this (as expected, as the member function pointer is non const and requires a non const T to bind on).

I'm concerned with regards to the lambda behaviour (I EXPECTED IT TO NOT COMPILE, AS WITH getFoo2). Any insights would be welcome.

Note: Compiler used GCC 4.8.*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct X
{
    void foo(){ std::cout << " non const !!!! foo called" << std::endl;}

    std::function<void()> getFoo1() const
    {
        //Compiles, even though "non const" this required...
        return [this]{foo();};
    }

    std::function<void()> getFoo2() const
    {
        //Fails to compiler due to non const this required
        return std::bind(&X::foo, this);
    }
};

int main() 
{

    X().getFoo1()();
    X().getFoo2()();
    return 0;
}
```

Kind regards,

Werner

Comment: What compiler are you using? To me, GCC 4.8.4 compiles fine getFoo1, but gives error on getFoo2

Comment: Yes. I'ts supposed to give an error for getFoo2. This is deliberate and expected. GCC 4.8.4, for that matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [defect in older versions of gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60463). Versions of gcc from 5.1.0 onwards, and of other compilers (clang, MSVC, ICC) correctly refuse to compile the code.

```
main.cpp: In lambda function:
main.cpp:11:27: error: passing 'const X' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
         return [this]{foo();};
                           ^
main.cpp:6:10: note:   in call to 'void X::foo()'
     void foo(){ std::cout << " non const !!!! foo called" << std::endl;}
          ^
```

Comment: g++ 4.9.2 gave me an error on this code, which, while indecipherable due to pointing to <functional>  code, went away if I made foo() const.